# Is it possible to fix a .png file with a hex editor?

Tags: format, hex, png, digital-signature, file-extension

I have bunch of **.png** files from the asset folder of an android game.I derived all assets from the .obb file. Every other file can be opened. But any of these .png files seem not to opened. I tried many of the concerning programs; Illustrator, Photoshop, GIMP, Paint and some online file viewers. But none of them could do.

---

Then I checked the hex code of the files and realized that those files **do not start with** usual png header which is

```
89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A
```

But all **ended with**

```
49 45 4E 44 AE 42 60 82
```

which belongs to png format.
[Checked .PNG Signature Here](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html)

So I tried to add png header to the files and then saved them. I had no idea if it was gonna work, just tried. Still I was not able to open those files.

---

So is there a way to open these files as images or can they be just some kind of data formatted as .png and not intended to using as images?

If it is about adding hex header, how should I do it?

---

[First Page of Hex Code](http://snag.gy/y9Dp3.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying random stuff. Upload one of these files on a public server and use [edit] to add a link to it into your post here, and we'll have a look.

Comment: Just added one to the post

Comment: Please show the next 8 bytes after the header.  They should contain a four-byte number 13 followed by "IHDR".

Comment: I am not familiar with hex codes. So I just checked what IHDR is. And see that it should be in .png files. But the thing is the one I have provided has nothing like "IHDR" in ANSI side.

Comment: Just posted ss from hex code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hex code shows about 500 bytes of garbage followed by a valid PNG tRNS chunk.  So apparently something has overwritten the beginning of the PNG files.  It would be possible, but a lot of work, to create the proper IHDR, PLTE, and possibly other chunks that are missing.  The information needed to do that is not contained in your file so you'd need to find that out elsewhere or by experimenting.

The fact that it has a 64-byte tRNS chunk tells you that the PNG colortype has to be 3 (indexed) and that the bit depth has to be 8, and suggests that there are only 64 different colors present. The palette contents are anyone's guess, so you could put in a simple 64-entry grayscale palette; this would make the image visible but without the proper colors.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. If that's the case I should better check folders to find out the cause overriding.

Comment: I've read the PNG spec and attempted a PNG decoder/encoder...For me that is already near impossible. Fixing a broken PNG? Better be a genius.